# SQL- Transpose data with one value per group

Tags: sql, teradata

I have items with different codes and dates associated with them. For codes P and L, I want to return the min date associated with the code as a new column. For code D, I want to return the max date as a new column. My data looks like this:

```
Item    Code    Date
ABC     P       11/24/2017 13:01
ABC     L       11/24/2017 16:30
ABC     P       11/25/2017 12:30
ABC     L       11/25/2017 20:24
ABC     D       11/26/2017 21:34
ABC     D       11/26/2017 23:16
ABD     P       10/5/2017 9:30
ABD     L       10/5/2017 13:23
ABD     L       10/6/2017 3:04
ABD     D       10/7/2017 8:31
```

The desired result is this:

```
Item    Code_P              Code_L              Code_D
ABC     11/24/2017 13:01    11/24/2017 16:30    11/26/2017 23:16
ABD     10/5/2017 9:30      10/5/2017 13:23     10/7/2017 8:31
```

So each item has one line, with Codes P and L showing the minimum value, and Code D having the maximum. Any ideas how to go about this? I'm using Teradata. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select item,
       max(case when code = 'P' then date end) as p_date,
       max(case when code = 'L' then date end) as l_date,
       max(case when code = 'D' then date end) as s_date
from t
group by item;
```